# Solving system of 4 equations in 4 unknowns using R

Tags: r, math

I am trying to solve the following 4 equations in 4 unknowns using R:

m_1 = 1 + p_{11}m_1 + p_{12}m_2 + p_{13} m_3 + p_{14} m_4,

m_2 = 1 + p_{21}m_1 + p_{22}m_2 + p_{23} m_3 + p_{24} m_4,

m_3 = 1 + p_{31}m_1 + p_{32}m_2 + p_{33} m_3 + p_{34} m_4,

m_4 = 1 + p_{41}m_1 + p_{42}m_2 + p_{43} m_3 + p_{44} m_4.

The p_{ij} values are known, and I want to solve for the m_i values.

Apparently, this should be able to be solved recursively.

How can this be done?

### Edit

`T <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1), nrow = 4) solve(T, c(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4))`

I get the following error message:

`Error in solve.default(T, c(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4)) : object 'm_1' not found`

Comment: check out `?solve`

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks, but I'm confused as to how this would be implemented for this type of recursive system? Would we have something like `a <- matrix(c(1, p_{11}, p_{12}, p_{13}, p_{14}, ...))`? But what about `b`? In this case, `b` is a vector of unknowns, so this is not clear to me. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to R

Comment: you need to rearrange your equations in to Ax = b e.g. `b = c(1,1,1,1)` and `A = matrix(c(1-p_11, -p_12, ...)`

Comment: @chinsoon12 Oh, so it's ok to have it as a vector of unknowns? The examples I saw were all values, so I wasn't sure if it would work. I will try it now. Thank you.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Inputting the values of the p_{ij}, I have `T <- matrix(c(1 + 0.5%*%m_1 + 0.5%*%m_2, 1 + 0.5%*%m_3, 
              1 + 0.5%*%m_1 + 0.5%*%m_4, 1 + m_4))
solve(T, c(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4))` I get the error `Error in matrix(c(1 + 0.5 %*% m_1 + 0.5 %*% m_2, 1 + 0.5 %*% m_3, 1 +  : 
  object 'm_1' not found`

Comment: Re your post on Math.SE: asking for an explanation behind how this is solved recursively, which is a mathematical problem, is openly welcomed. What's not welcomed is asking about specifics to programming, which I fail to see asked there.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I made a mistake; I am interested in how this is programmed to be solved in R.

Comment: Just making it clear 

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's fine. Do you happen to know how I can do this in R?

Comment: No but I can show how to do this in another language (C, Java, python, Ruby) if you'd like that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ahh, yes please! Python would be nice if possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Python 3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/)

```python
def solve(p, iterations = 16, m1 = 0.0, m2 = 0.0, m3 = 0.0, m4 = 0.0):
  for n in range(iterations):
    m1 = 1 + p[0][0]*m1 + p[0][1]*m2 + p[0][2]*m3 + p[0][3]*m4
    m2 = 1 + p[1][0]*m1 + p[1][1]*m2 + p[1][2]*m3 + p[1][3]*m4
    m3 = 1 + p[2][0]*m1 + p[2][1]*m2 + p[2][2]*m3 + p[2][3]*m4
    m4 = 1 + p[3][0]*m1 + p[3][1]*m2 + p[3][2]*m3 + p[3][3]*m4
  return m1, m2, m3, m4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdBNCsIwEAXgvaeYpT9VOjPFheBJxEXBVAs2CWkUevo4tTSdQhbvEb5ZPD/El7N89IMfUnqYBnr3/pqtL6CNJtSxdbaHK@C5gA4llKdSEuXEOVVT2l02AI0LYKG1EGr7NNvl1P8XplMIB/C38i5v3@WCUmguJIXnwlKqiVPmqDlqjprjinPmpDlpTprTileZs@asOWvOCw8mfoKVAcYVx/3G5VL6AQ)

We apply the [Gauss-Seidal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) with 16 iterations and initial values of all zeros. Iteratively we then update each `m` based on the previous values.

Note that convergence is not guaranteed. For a test case where it converges, you can try

```python
p = [[0.3, 0.2 , 0.1 , 0.2],
     [0.2,-0.4 , 0.2 , 0.1],
     [0.1,-0.2 , 0.3 , 0.2],
     [0.0, 0.07, 0.03, 0.1]]
```

Comment: I modified it for my case. Is this correct?[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LDsIgEEX3fsVdVm1NedhFEz@miVRJ7EAomvD1CMWgC3dn5uTOXBv83ZDobLAhxquasZrHSzW2hfbKTV4bWnEBG1osLEF/6hPxSqKSLLQfd8BsHAia4Ca6qeZ7arMopxiOKXA@LBV4kfxXirITfwOySPmR2@yUfzpKL3LP3DB3i/EN "Python 3 (PyPy) – Try It Online") I don't get any output; did I do something wrong?

Comment: You can use `print(solve(p))` where `p` is from above to see the result.

Comment: For your modified code you can use [this](https://tio.run/##bY9JDsIwDEX3PYWXDZOaARZIHKYSKUSiTuQGpJw@JDWKumD37Cfb3yHFp0d9DCmknO92gsW/PrZ30dIYnccFbiAvB5hlgeE0FFKNdCPDJK4dwOQJEBwCjfjYrlot8CoJ@zJw3s0NFEu1lZp7@u@AYWl@cq3JxjdhOVFz1oQ1W9cFchh7fk2InL8).

Comment: Thank you for that. The output is `(8.325393438339233, 6.9970937967300415, 12.662696719169617, 16.0)`. So is m_4 = 16? or is that the number of iterations? So m_1 = 8.3, m_2 = 7, m_3 = 12.7, m_4 = 16?

Comment: `m_4` just happens to be 16 it seems. You can input an integer argument into the `solve` e.g. `solve(100)` to do 100 iterations to get more accurate results or see if it diverges.

Comment: 100 results in the output `(36.33333333333333, 35.0, 68.66666666666666, 100.0)`. Are you sure this is correct? It seems that it is changing drastically depending on the iterations.

Comment: One can see that we should actually expect divergence in your case, there is no solution to the equation `m_4 = 1 + m_4`.

Comment: You can try [my test case](https://tio.run/##ZZHRasMwDEXf8xV6TNY0WFJYobAvCXkozF0Dq2Ncd5Cvz@R4dVUGRtzr6yOB7Jd4mR3v/eKXdf20Z7jN3z@29i1M0YZTnGZ3gw/A9xauKMJ0RhQVxUX1WTXHCuA8B3AwOQgn92XrZ6sthdwKYQd@MKOct2sxKIYehsTww7CYPuNUcNQ4ahw1ji84F5w0ThonjdML3hecNc4aZ43zEw823oOTBaQtpv2lzVWVl5bDYDqxpiNIFbdKY7sNBQmp3ZuuB/VEhZjCfM3/SJMuzGGrnMlRhobJxfrvw5tmXX8B), which actually converges.

Comment: Take [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5dCsIwEAbfc4p9bKqV/FlawcMUTDVgNiGNQk4fGwPRt4GdHT6f4sOhHHzyKeebXmFzz7fuTNRhicbhBlfgjB3B8p3YqZBoJBupSvRCAFYXAMEghAXv/63vFWqKw6E8qGnqbeX5zMbeiqqInyJn0ZSRqaoEHV8B91TZQ4gPBmNXt1Oa8wc "Python 3 (PyPy) – Try It Online") this case. It is said that this example is m_1 = 2451.0 days and m_2 = 2451.5 days. But the code results in the output `(101.70209141271518, 101.7618686229708)`

Comment: The convergence in that example is just extremely slow (since the initial guess was far off). You can see that by raising the amount of iterations to, say a million, or by changing the initial values for `m_1, m_2`, it'll converge faster.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Example using R `base::solve`:

```
solve(diag(4L) - P, rep(1, 4L))
#[1] 5.333333 3.333333 4.666667 2.000000
```

data:

```
P <- structure(c(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), 
    .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
P
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
#[3,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.5
#[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
```